# Enhanced FTP pros and cons or any documentation on Single Account FTP vs Multi-Account FTP on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

I am looking for any documentation or details on Single Account FTP vs Multi-Account FTP.

We are having multiple business unit and wants to know the pros and cons on Single Account FTP vs Multi-Account FTP so that i can understand more on the Enchanced FTP setup.

[Enhanced FTP Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240691&type=1)  This the only document i found in my research which haven't specified any details on  Single Account FTP vs Multi-Account FTP

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple FTP accounts (one per BU) is rather new within SFMC. The documentation around it is not well established. Thinking through how the FTP works there are two major differences.

1. User access. Depending on how your users will be accessing the FTP it may be easier to have one log in where they can access folders for all BUs or you may want to restrict access to some BU files.
2. The FTP folders should only be monitored from one BU when using Triggered Automatons. If you have two automation within different BUs watching a single folder, this will cause problems. The typical behavior is that which ever automation was turned on last will trigger and the other automation(s) will not.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for the quick response our goal is to set up Separate log in for each BU along with separate folder for each BU so that the automation can point to the individual folder.  I cam across Multiple FTP Account is this functionality can be used for Multiple Business unit as i am not able to find any documentations on it . I would like to know the differences or functionalities of Single/Multiple Account FTP.